# Turning the id to count number in grails

Tags: jquery, grails, count, html-table, element

Listing a id of items in a table
which looks like:

`<g:sortableColumn style="width: 20px" property="id" title="${message(code: 'packet.id.label', default: 'Id')}" />`

```
<g:each in="${packetInstanceList}" status="i" var="packetInstance">
          <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

             <td><g:link controller="packet" action="show"  id="${packetInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: packetInstance, field: "id")}
</g:link></td>
```

Shows me id of the items from domain packet.

I would like to turn them into a count, 
which starts from 1, independent from id number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<g:each in="${packetInstanceList}" status="i" var="packetInstance">
  <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
    <td>
      <g:link controller="packet" action="show"  id="${packetInstance.id}">${i + 1}</g:link> 
    </td>
```

Comment: this is awesome! works pretty perfect, thats very interesting

Answer (score 1):

`var cnt = $("td [id!='']").length();` won't work?

This is jQuery btw.

[.length()](http://api.jquery.com/length/) gets the total number of elements currently matched. The .size() method will return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly, you want to output the i that you already set for the each loop incremented by 1 cause its 0-based like

```
<g:link controller="packet" action="show" id="${packetInstance.id}">
    ${i+1}
</g:link>
```